# Mule 4 Embedded runtime in web application

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb, mule4

I am using Mule 3 embedded runtime in a web application deployed in wildfly using the MuleXmlBuilderContextListener class, I want to migrate to Mule 4 but I cannot find any procedure concerning embedded runtime in the official documentation unlike version 3, nor the dependence to use for this case.
Is there a sample anywhere showing this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mule 4 doesn't support to be embedded at this time.

Comment: Thanks for this response, is there any official documentation that says that?